# How to add Images Dynamically in a List View With the click of camera

Tags: android, listview

currently i am working on a application in which i have to add images dynamically into a List View with click of camera , i have gone through from multiple examples but i am not getting answer. so please provide me the code or the link using that i can solve my problem. Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what you mean 'click of camera'

Comment: 1.your listview and camera button resides on the same activity?   OR  2.after capturing and saving the image you are passing it to next activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving Some idea how you can achieve this :

- Write **Camera Code Function()** which should return Bitmap
- Create a Bitmap type list **ArrayList Camera_Image_List = new ArrayList();**
- Create your **Custom List** view which having image and some other control if you want [like](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
- Call **Camera Code Function()** when user wants to snap & add bitmap in   **Camera_Image_List** which is return by function.
- **Task over**